# Framework for uploading images with titles to Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I see in the internet codes that do upload images but the use "Facebook" that isn't recognized, so which framework do I need to use in iOS?
Do you have a code example?
I found this code:

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = @"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:img, @"picture", @"my photo's caption text here.", @"message", nil];
    [facebook requestWithMethodName: @"photos.upload" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
    [img release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the Facebook iOS SDK to your project.

All the details you need should be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)